# Pushnotification not received when install ipa file

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, push-notification

Pushnotification not received when install ipa file using developer mode.
**Two days before it was work fine.**
I am able to receive pushnotification if install via Xcode. But, not receives after makes ipa file (Budle Id and code signing part is correct).

I have tested the following websites too,

http://pushtry.com/

http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/

Answer (score 1):

When you take build from Xcode it will be development mode. And you stated "I am able to receive pushnotification if install via Xcode".So that means in server side development APNS certificate is implemeted and the certificate is valid.

So check following:
1) While taking IPA file(archiving), are you taking development build (see [image]).

If you take other builds then you need to implement distribution APNS certificate in the server, coz the IPA will be distribution/production build.

Answer (score 0):

Things to Consider in Push Notification
Development Mode , Certificate in server must be development. And send push to `tls://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195`

Any mismatch will cause push not receiving issue.

https://apn-tester-free.en.softonic.com/mac

you can use this app for testing development.